# Issues Within The style.css of wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, adsense

is there a CSS method to get rid of the white box behind the Google ad on my Wordpress site [here](http://www.ledgetechs.com)

Is it possible to get rid of the white box behind the Google ad only and not the other widgets within the sidebar. If this is not possible, is there a way the box could be shrunken with css?

I assumed if I went to the widgets section of the style.css file I could resolve the issue there, but I tried editing this snippet of code but I couldn't find anything that could resolve this issue.this is probably the wrong location where the issue could be found which is why I provided the full script here.

I hope my issue makes sense as this is my first stack overflow question

Full CSS file [here](http://www.ledgetechs.com/wp-content/themes/the-box/style.css?ver=1.4.9.1)

The script below is the section I tried editing one time

```css
/* 
 * 09: Widgets
 */

.widget {
 margin: 0 0 20px;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 color: #757575;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.widget-title {
 color: #353535;
 font-size: 1.154em;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 line-height: 1.3;
}

.widget ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.widget li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.widget p:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.widget_archive li a:before,
.widget_links li a:before,
.widget_categories li a:before,
.widget_meta li a:before,
.widget_recent_entries li a:before,
.widget_recent_comments li .comment-author-link:before {
 font-family: "icons-font" !important;
 font-style: normal !important;
 font-weight: normal !important;
 font-variant: normal !important;
 text-transform: none !important;
 speak: none;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 font-size: 14px;
 width: 14px;
 text-align: left;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: -15%;
}

.widget_archive li a:before,
.widget_links li a:before,
.widget_categories li a:before,
.widget_meta li a:before,
.widget_recent_entries li a:before {
 content: "\66";
}

.widget_recent_comments li .comment-author-link:before {
 content: "\4a";
 padding-right: 0.25em;
}

.widget select {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.widget_media_image img {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try     background-color: transparent;

```
#custom_html-4 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for temporary solution by css you can use. if you need to hide only white background from yellow box

```css
div#custom_html-4{
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
}
```